# Kubernetes post-install job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I have a kubernetes job with post-install hook. Sometimes this hook fails but I want the helm upgrade to still succeed and ignore failures in post-install job. Is this doable?

Comment: Can you just alter your job so it just always exits "0", even when it fails?

Comment: Yes, I have to chain the bash commands with `./job.sh || exit 0`. It works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For clarity and future visitors with similar requirement, I'm posting a solution as *Community Wiki* based on hint from @alltej:

> Alter your job so it just always exits "0"

For instance:

```
./job.sh || exit 0
```